# Validar un campo select

Tags: bootstrap, jquery-validate

Actualización de la pregunta. Necesito validar un Select con jquery.validate y bootstrap antes de registrar, de lo contrario que mande la alerta. Tengo la tabla casa y la tabla apuesta, en el formulario selecciono es el id de la tabla casa para saber el nombre de la casa, y es ese selecc el que necesito validar. Ver imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se ve en la imagen 2, que después de seleccionar la casa de apuesta sigue validando como si no se hubiera seleccionado nada.
El código utilizado en el formulario es este:

```html
<form action="registrar_apuesta.php" method="GET" name="myform" id="myform">  
    <div class="row">                                                                                   
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_casa">Casa de Apuesta *:</label>
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                    </span> 
                    <select id="id_casa" class="form-control" name="id_casa">
                        <?php
                        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'apuestas');
                        ?>
                        <option value="0">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                        <?php
                        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM casa order by nombre_ca asc");

                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_casa'] . '">' . $valores['nombre_ca'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>                                                 
                </div> 
                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">    
                <label for="valor_apostado" class="form-control-label">Valor Apostado *</label>
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                    </span> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_apostado" name="valor_apostado" placeholder="" required="true">                                                    
                </div>
                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                               
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Cerrar</button>
</form>
```

El código utilizado para la validación es este:

```js
// JavaScript Validation For Registration Page

$('document').ready(function ()
{
    var combb = / /;
    $.validator.addMethod("combo", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || combb.test(value);
    });

    var nameregex = /[0-9]/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validvalorapos", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || nameregex.test(value);
    });

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules:
                {
                    id_casa: {
                        required: true,
                        combo: true,
                    },
                    valor_apostado: {
                        required: true,
                        validvalorapos: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                },
        messages:
                {                    
                    id_casa: {
                        required: "Seleccione una casa de Apuesta",
                        combo: "Seleccione una casa de Apuesta",
                    },
                    valor_apostado: {
                        required: "Ingrese el Valor Apostado",
                        validvalorapos: "Sólo se pueden Ingresar Números",
                        minlength: "Su Nombre es Demasiado Corto"
                    },
                },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor de un `select` la forma corta es:

```
$('select').val();
```

para evitar el envió puedes poner un `return false;`

aparte tienes un problema con el `if` ya que validas `0 == ""` y esto retorna `false`

```
$(".validar_form").submit(function (e) {
    var select = $("select").val();

    if (select == 0) {
        $('.error').text("Seleccione una Casa de Apuestas");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.errors').hide();
        alert('OK');
    }
});
```

Comment: También hice los cambios sugeridos por @JuanKGlezz y tampoco

Comment: tu `value` de los `options` que valor contienen? números o texto?

Comment: contienen números, pues es la llave foranea que hace referencia a otra tabla.

Comment: @Scorpion he arreglado la respuesta, no funciona la validación de un numero con un texto

Comment: Nada, no me funciona

Comment: Aclaro que el el select trae los datos de una tabla y el campo de  valor_apostado pertenece a otra tabla

Answer (score 0):

Mira aqui:

```
<option value="0">-- Seleccionar --</option>
```

Tienes que el valor por defecto si no se selecciona ninguna opcion es `0` pero en el script tienes:

```
var select = $("select option:selected").val();    
if (select == "") 
//..
```

Cuando debería de ser :

```
 var select = $("select option:selected").val();    
 if (select == "0")
```

Si no tienes definido jquery agrega esta etiqueta script al principio de la pagina:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <div class="modal-body">
     ...
```

Comment: Hice los cambios sugeridos pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Dale un vistazo a la respuesta que la actualize.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Estraño, [me funciona correctamente](http://jsbin.com/liqoteqoki/edit?html,js,console,output). Tienes algun otro `select` en el formulario?

Comment: Solamente tengo ese, ese es el código del formulario, tengo otros select pero en otros formualrios y no creo que genere conflicto

Comment: Algun error en la consola?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62409/discussion-between-scorpion-and-einer).

Comment: O alguien tiene otra forma de validar un select?

Comment: Hice un ejemplo que funciona correctamente. Pudiste ver la consola precionando F12 como te mencione?

Comment: En console me sale: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Te agregar la referencia de Jquery en tu pagina. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: @Scorpion si te funciono, me dejas saber.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, también intente de esta forma y nada:  <script>
 $(function()
{
    $("#myform").validate(
      {
        rules: 
        {
          id_casa: 
          {
            required: true
          }
        }
      }); 
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu PHP y añade un ID al select y cambia el valor 0

```
<select class="form-control" name="id_casa" id="id_casa">
 <option selected disabled>-- Seleccionar --</option>
</select>
```

Con jquery haz esto

```
$(".validar_form").submit(function () {
var select = $("#id_casa").val();
if (select == null) {
    $('.error').text("Seleccione una Casa de Apuestas");
    return false;
} else {
    $('.errors').hide();
    alert('OK');
    return true;
}
});
```

Eso debería funcionar

Comment: Agradezco a todos por sus comentarios, pero no logre dar solución al problema, ahora estoy intentando con jqueryvalidate, hago una nueva pregunta y doy por concluida esta o edito la pregunta original por la nueva, cuál es el procedimiento correcto?

Answer (score 0):

Compadre deje vacio el option:

```
<select id="id_casa" class="form-control" name="id_casa">
                    <?php
                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'apuestas');
                    ?>
                    <option value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                    <?php
                    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM casa order by nombre_ca asc");

                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_casa'] . '">' . $valores['nombre_ca'] . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Y prueba ahora.